# how to use the dist floder build with gulp in production

Tags: angularjs, xampp, gulp

i am currently learning gulp with an angularjs project. here is my project structure.

```
/gultuto
/app
/dist
    /css
        style.min.css
    /fonts
    /js
        app.min.js
        vendor.min.js
/node_modules
    .bowerrc
    .editorconfig
    .gitgnore
    .jshintrc
    brower.json
    Gulpfile.js
    package.json
    README.md
```

when i run the `gulp command` it build the dist file successfully 
Now i need tu take the /dist folder into my another server like 
`xampp(local server)`. but after copy the `/dist` into my `xampp/htdocs` it doesn't work soo i really need someone to help me.